# Better way to go to background in a running command

Tags: shell, terminal, background-process, job-control, jobs

Actually I do this to bring a running command from the foreground into the background:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

and then

```
bg
```

There is a better way?

Because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> just pause the process and after that I need to run `bg` to unpause it. But I think this is like a jerry-rig.

Note: don't say to me run the process with `&`, I want a command for doing this when the command is already running.

Comment: That's the standard way to do it.  There is no way to send the current process to background with a single keystroke.